# angular predicate filter not returning element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to use a predicate function to filter some items because the object structure might be a little too deep for straight template filtering. I have an array of items that I'm tring to filter based on user selected region and user selected country. When I filter the items in the template with the selected region the correct items are rendered. However, I need to filter deeper i.e., the user selects countries of the selected region. The predicate function appears to be filtering the items correctly i.e., printing to console, but the items are not rendering in the template.

```
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "my test app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "regions": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "LATIN_AMERICA",
        "timeZone": "UTC+8",
        "selected": true,
        "countries": [
          {
            "id": 47,
            "name": "Brazil",
            "timeZone": "UTC+08:00",
            "isoCode": "BR",
            "selected": false
          },
          {
            "id": 46,
            "name": "Argentina",
            "timeZone": "UTC+08:00",
            "isoCode": "AR",
            "selected": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "my test app",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "regions": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "LATIN_AMERICA",
        "timeZone": "UTC+8",
        "selected": true,
        "countries": [
          {
            "id": 47,
            "name": "Brazil",
            "timeZone": "UTC+08:00",
            "isoCode": "BR",
            "selected": true
          },
          {
            "id": 46,
            "name": "Argentina",
            "timeZone": "UTC+08:00",
            "isoCode": "AR",
            "selected": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

function filterByRegionCountry(app) {
    if(vm.selectedCountry !== undefined) {
        angular.forEach(app.regions, function(appRegion, i) {
            angular.forEach(appRegion.countries, function(appCountry, j) {
                angular.forEach(vm.selectedCountry, function(selectedCountry, k) {
                    if((appCountry.name == selectedCountry.name) && appCountry.selected) {
                        console.log(app);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
}

<select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selectedRegion" ng-options="region.name for region in vm.filterRegions">
    <option value="">--select region--</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selectedCountry" ng-options="country.name for country in vm.selectedRegion.countries" multiple>
    <option value="">-- select country --</option>
</select>

<tr ng-repeat="app in vm.appVersions | filter:vm.filterByRegionCountry">
    <td>
        <label>{{ app.name }}</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>{{ app.version }}</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

// EDIT 
Using .some (see answer below) or for loops with a break fixes the issue.

```
    if(vm.selectedCountry !== undefined) {
        for(var i = 0; i < app.regions.length; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < app.regions[i].countries.length; j++) {
                for(var k = 0; k < vm.selectedCountry.length; k++) {
                    if((app.regions[i].countries[j].name == vm.selectedCountry[k].name) && app.regions[i].countries[j].selected) {
                        console.log(app);
                        return true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)** need either `true` or `false` to exevalue.

You are using angular [**forEach**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) and there no break for **[forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)**

Try javascript **[.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** instead

like this

```
if (vm.selectedCountry) {
    return app.regions.some(function (appRegion) {
        return appRegion.countries.some(function (appCountry) {
            return vm.selectedCountry.some(function (selectedCountry) {
                if ((appCountry.name == selectedCountry.name) && appCountry.selected) {
                    console.log(app);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
    });

} 
else 
  return false;
```

Comment: Awesome! I've never heard of .some before. So, using .some or changing to for loops with a break after return true fixes the issue. Thanks!